# File Not Found when opening to read a file

Tags: c#, io, streamreader

I enter a path name and a file name into my program, that works enough, and eventually the path might be something like

```
path = @"C:\ ...\";
```

Where the ... is just the rest of the path to the directory where the below file is located.

```
file = "something.txt";
```

But I get a file not found when I execute this:

```
System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(path+file);
```

I'm confused as to what I'm doing wrong. Am I just not using this correctly?

I'm an idiot sorry, I found out what I was doing wrong.

Comment: Please post the related code.

Comment: Did you escape the backslashes?

Comment: The file does exist. I did create a file called something.txt. And I escaped with the @ sign right? doesn't that count/

Comment: `path+file` in there is bad news bears.  Use Path.Combine() or at least test it exists before attempting to read it.

Comment: Okay I didn't use path+file, I set the full path to just a 'path' variable. But I still get a FNF exception.

Comment: Does your app have access to the path/file?  BTW, check in debug mode the result of `path+file`, it may not have the right path/file name.

Comment: I printed out the name of the path to console, I assure you that's correct. And I run Visual Studio as administrator so it should be able to see the file system right?

Answer (score 3):

You can try to use [`Path.Combine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), but if you assign your full path directly to a single variable it would better,I don't understand why are you doing this by the way.

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Path.Combine(path,file));
```

Note: Delete last backslash from the `path` variable

Comment: Even if I concatenate both the path and the file beforehand, and just have the full path in a single variable, the reader still gives me a File not found error.

Comment: then check your path and make sure your file **exist**

Comment: I'm positive it exists, I created it and stored it right next to where my code is located so I don't know what's going on

Comment: I found out what I did wrong, sorry it was stupid

Answer (score 2):

Create a `FileInfo` object to make your life a bit easier.

```
FileInfo file = FileInfo(Path.Combine(path,file));
if(!file.Exists)
    throw new FileNotFoundException("File Not Found or Inaccessable"); //or handle approprately

 using(StreamReader reader = file.OpenText())
 {
      //do reading stuff here
 }
```

Comment: Remember you'll get a `FileNotFoundException` even if the file exists, but the application does not have access to read that file, or get to that location.

Comment: Yeah I think I should be less lazy and throw exceptions as well on my own. But my problem was due to stupid mistakes on my part. Thank you for your input I'll keep this suggestion in mind though for other uses